# Confusion regarding height of binary tree

Tags: c, binary-tree

Suppose my tree looks like this

```
     5
   /  \
  1    8 
      /  \
     6    9
```

I have written a program to find the height of this.

```
     65 int height(const TNODE* root) {                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 66         if (root == NULL) {                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 67                 return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 68         } else {                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 69                 int lDepth = height(root->left);                                                                                                                                                                                          
 70                 int rDepth = height(root->right);                                                                                                                                                                                         
 71                 if (lDepth > rDepth) {                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 72                         return (lDepth + 1);                                                                                                                                                                                              
 73                 } else {                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 74                         return (rDepth + 1);                                                                                                                                                                                              
 75                 }                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 76                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 77         }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 78 }
```

Running this method prints 3 for the tree above. But shouldn't the height be 2 since that is the number of edges from the root to the furthest leaf? I've searched online and I got contradicting information. Some would say that my tree above has a height of 3 while others say 2.

So what height should my tree above be and why?

Is my method correct?

Comment: It clearly depends on your application. Choose that matches you expectation according you application.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: @igon I've added some clarifications.

Comment: 2 edges height and always 2 + 1 nodes height. It depends whether you count the nodes or the edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "height" is a little too generic here.  Either 2 or 3 could be the correct answer, depending on the precise definition.

For example, if I state the height of the tree is the number of "levels" it contains, 3 is the correct answer.  But, if I state the height of the tree is the maximum number of edges to cross to get to a leaf, without crossing an edge more than once (i.e. no back-tracking), then 2 is the correct answer.

In my experience the more common answer would be 3.  The tree has 3 levels.  A tree with only a root node has a height of 1.  I prefer that, as an empty tree would then have height of 0.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion regarding the style.

```
  int height(const TNODE* root) {                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    if (root == NULL) {                                                                                                                                                                                                               
       return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    } else {                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      int lDepth = height(root->left);                                                                                                                                                                                          
      int rDepth = height(root->right);  
      return max ( lDepth, rDepth )  + 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                   
     }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  }
```